# Есть ли возможность отследить обновление страницы при нажатии кнопки браузера reload до момента перезагрузки?

Tags: javascript

Есть ли возможность отследить событие браузера до момента как она перезагрузится, что бы можно было удалить web worker -а

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы ищете эти два события: `window.onbeforeunload` и `window.onunload`. Между этими событиями загружается следующая страница.

Подробнее можно найти на страницах:
[спецификации](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#unloading-documents),  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event)

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => { /* Событие возникает при попытке
                                   уйти со страницы
                                   ( клик по reload или ссылке ) */ };       

window.onunload = () => { /* Следующая страница загружена,
                             текущая страница выключается, 
                             можно останавливать воркеры */ };
```

Comment: Посмотрел в тестах. Эти методы не надёжные и не рекомендуютсчя к использованию.

The `unload` event does not fire reliably and listening for it can prevent browser optimizations like the Back-Forward Cache. Consider using the `pagehide` or `visibilitychange` events instead. Learn more

Comment: @Sergey Все методы ненадежные. Однако unload работает во всех браузерах, которые его поддерживают и никуда не собирался в статус deprecated. По поводу надежности, есть хорошая статья [Beaconing in practice](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2020/beaconing-in-practice/). Там наглядно в диаграммах приведены результаты тестов, на сколько pagehide работает надёжнее - [74.8% против 72.2%](https://nicj.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/all-unload.svg). Что касается visibilitychange - это вообще не то событие и срабатывает оно гораздо чаще, при переключении вкладок или окна приложения, вам оно надо было?

Comment: ну я приложение как контейнер буду использовать для приложений android и iphone поэтому да надо. Я и вопрос во многом из за этого задал. Мне надо сотояние service worker -а контролировать. И получилось так. что для мобильных приложений и десктопа инициализация воркера работает по разному. В общем буду смотреть. Google тоже если предупреждение выдаёт , тоже ведь не просто так.